# Uso de funciones entre notebooks en deepnote

Tags: python

Estoy intentando importar una función desde otro notebook llamado ANALISIS_POBLACIONAL_1 hacia el notebook sobre el que estoy trabajando el cual es ANALISIS POBLACIONAL 2.0 que esta en el mismo proyecto en deepnote, pero al hacerlo de la manera habitual en la que se importan módulos en Python, no funciona y dice que el modulo no se encuentra, he tratado como muestra la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pense que quizas era por los espacios asi que se los retire, aun asi no funciona.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.